# MongoDB>DataNucleus>JPA Query using "MEMBER OF" working

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, jpql, datanucleus

With

```
Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT chat FROM Chat chat WHERE :user MEMBER OF chat.members");
```

or

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Chat> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Chat.class);
Root<Chat> chatRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Chat.class);

Expression<Collection<User>> membersExpression = chatRoot.get("members");
ParameterExpression<User> userParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(User.class);
Predicate containsGroup = criteriaBuilder.isMember(userParameter, membersExpression);
criteriaQuery.where(containsGroup);
TypedQuery query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setParameter(userParameter, this);
```

I just recieve what I want and

```
DEBUG Cache - Query Cache of type "org.datanucleus.query.cache.SoftQueryCompilationCache" initialised
DEBUG Cache - Query Cache of type "org.datanucleus.store.query.cache.SoftQueryDatastoreCompilationCache" initialised
DEBUG Cache - Query Cache of type "org.datanucleus.store.query.cache.SoftQueryResultsCache" initialised
DEBUG Query - JPQL Single-String with "SELECT DN_THIS FROM com.resocial.beans.Chat DN_THIS WHERE :DN_PARAM_0 MEMBER OF DN_THIS.members"
DEBUG Query - QueryCompilation:
  [from:ClassExpression(alias=DN_THIS)]
  [filter:InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{DN_THIS.members}].contains(ParameterExpression{DN_PARAM_0})}]
  [symbols: DN_THIS type=com.resocial.beans.Chat, DN_PARAM_0 type=unknown]
DEBUG Connection - Created DB from MongoClient
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@1119d93 [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is starting
DEBUG Persistence - Managing Persistence of Class : com.resocial.beans.Chat [Table : (none), InheritanceStrategy : complete-table]
DEBUG Schema - Ensuring presence of index "Chat_PK" for collection "Chat" as "{ "id" : 1}"
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@1119d93 [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@1119d93 [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT DN_THIS FROM com.resocial.beans.Chat DN_THIS WHERE :DN_PARAM_0 MEMBER OF DN_THIS.members" for datastore
WARN  Query - FROM clause will be ignored. Not supported for this datastore (MongoDB doesn't do 'joins')
DEBUG Query - Compilation of filter to be evaluated completely in-datastore was impossible : 
Dont currently support querying of multi-valued fields at com.resocial.beans.Chat.members
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Dont currently support querying of multi-valued fields at com.resocial.beans.Chat.members
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.getFieldNameForPrimary(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:860)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.processPrimaryExpression(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:453)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.processInvokeExpression(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:630)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compilePrimaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileUnaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:182)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileAdditiveMultiplicativeExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:161)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileRelationalExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:136)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileOrAndExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:78)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:46)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.Expression.evaluate(Expression.java:338)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.compileFilter(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:176)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.compile(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:152)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JPQLQuery.java:400)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileInternal(JPQLQuery.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1816)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1762)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:202)
    ...
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Compile Time for datastore = 72 ms
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection found in the pool : "org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false]" for key="org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@a0497b" in factory="ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl@c9b10a]"
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is starting
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Executing "SELECT DN_THIS FROM com.resocial.beans.Chat DN_THIS WHERE :DN_PARAM_0 MEMBER OF DN_THIS.members" ...
DEBUG Native - Performing find() using query on collection Chat for fields={ "id" : 1} with filter={ } and ordering=null
INFO  Query - Reading in results for query "SELECT DN_THIS FROM com.resocial.beans.Chat DN_THIS WHERE :DN_PARAM_0 MEMBER OF DN_THIS.members" since the connection used is closing/committing
DEBUG Cache - Object with id "com.resocial.beans.Chat:51" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 2]
DEBUG Cache - Object with id "com.resocial.beans.Chat:51" not found in Level 2 cache
DEBUG Cache - Object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id="com.resocial.beans.Chat:51") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[YN]")
DEBUG Cache - Object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id="51") added to Level 2 cache (fields="[0]", version="")
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Processing the "filter" clause using in-memory evaluation (clause = "InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{DN_THIS.members}].contains(ParameterExpression{DN_PARAM_0})}")
DEBUG Query - Evaluating filter for 1 candidates
DEBUG Lifecycle - Object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id="com.resocial.beans.Chat:51") has a lifecycle change : "HOLLOW"->"P_NONTRANS"
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection found in the pool : "org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false]" for key="org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@a0497b" in factory="ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl@c9b10a]"
DEBUG Retrieve - Fetching object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id=51) fields [members]
DEBUG Retrieve - Object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id="51") being retrieved from MongoDB
DEBUG Native - Retrieving object for { "id" : 51}
 [...]
DEBUG Persistence - Object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id="com.resocial.beans.Chat:51") is having the value in field "members" replaced by a SCO wrapper
DEBUG Persistence - Created SCO wrapper of type org.datanucleus.store.types.wrappers.ArrayList for object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" field "members" with 2 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
DEBUG Retrieve - Execution Time = 111 ms
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
DEBUG Cache - Object "com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" (id="51") is having the following fields in Level 2 cache object updated : [1]
DEBUG Query - Evaluation of filter for candidate="com.resocial.beans.Chat@1f0347a" gives a match
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Execution Time = 298 ms
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@e96dbd [conn=com.mongodb.DB@ad7b11, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
```

in my log file.

What I want to get is, you guessed it already, a List with all chats where my user is listed as a member. Is there a persitence api way (only jpa, not datanucleus or mongodb specific) to achieve my goal?

And, yes, I am stuck to MongoDB 2.4 .

Comment: why not post what the query is compiled to from the log?

Comment: @NeilStockton, "SELECT DN_THIS FROM com.resocial.beans.Chat DN_THIS WHERE :DN_PARAM_3 MEMBER OF DN_THIS.members" is the jpql query from log, there is nothing else...

Comment: There will be messages like _[DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - Performing find() using query on collection SAMPLEACCOUNT for fields={ "name" : 1 , "saldo" : 1 , "Account_ID" : 1} with filter={ "name" : "alice"} and ordering=null_

Comment: @NeilStockton, actually yes, I overlooked it, there was this line _Performing find() using query on collection Chat for fields={ "id" : 1} with filter={ } and ordering=null_.

Comment: and before that in the log? the query compilation? Put it in your question.

Comment: @NeilStockton, here is my log file.

Comment: as the log says, it cannot do MEMBER OF in datastore, so it resolves that part in memory, and returns the result. hence it does "work"

Answer (score 0):

After changing your persistable classes `@Entit[ies]` you need to enhance them twice for a good reason (I did not understand, but it has to be good). When upgrading either to MongoDB 3.0 or higher or to DataNucleus 5.0 or higher you no longer need to do that.

Comment: No idea what is "reload twice" and "initialize advanced features", and indeed how that answers the question

Comment: @NeilStockton, problem while enhancing... but if it enhances twice it'll work, since you recommended the newest version of datanucleus, I don't need this anymore.

Comment: I have no "problem while enhancing" and I dont see any issue in their system, so suggest that the problem is how you are doing it

Comment: @NeilStockton, most likly, unlucky as I am I cannot reproduce it... Even with an older version of DataNucleus.